# how do you disable back button in a browser once the user logs in and once the user logs out in react?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router-dom

I'm building a user management system using react and spring boot. Currently when the user signs in, the user is redirected to the homepage. How do I disable the back button in the homepage? And similarly how do I disable the back button once the user signs out?

Comment: Simply: you don't. You have no control over that, because the browser won't let a site take over control like that. You have to make your site function within that limitation. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Controlling what a user sees should be done server-side. Only serve them the page if they have been successfully authenticated on the server. People generally store info in cookies for this.